# Other reasons why python venv is not working apart from ExecutionPolicy

Tags: python-venv, executionpolicy

I was wondering why running command activate in venv_name/Scripts is not working on one computer while on another with exactly same ExecutionPolicy settings it works.

Recently I've started to use new laptop and I had the problems with running the venv so I changed the policies and everything is ok. I made small research and peaked to PolicySettings in my old laptop and found out that it was set different so  on my old laptop I've set policy to settings same as original ones on my new laptop (the case when running activate command didn't work). And running virtual environment still works on old laptop! So that means there must be something else which affects activating virtual environment. Maybe OS (old laptop - Windows 10, new laptop - Windows 11)? Any ideas?